# Problem with = operator for STL set

Tags: c++, set, variable-assignment

I'm experiencing an error with the following code. The problem arises when I call `detect_H_conflicts` and `detect_L_conflicts`, at the very end of the code shown below, and use the = operator with msg.conflict_list_H and msg.conflict_list_L. The error is

> Graph.cpp:308: error: expected
>   unqualified-id before '.' token
>   Graph.cpp:309: error: expected
>   unqualified-id before '.' token

```
set<int> Graph::detect_H_conflicts(const vector<int>&v) { ... }
set<int> Graph::detect_L_conflicts(const vector<int>&v, int c) { ... }

struct msg {  // nested within Graph in Graph.h
    int sender;                 // sender id
    int sender_distance;        // sender distance to root node
    vector<int> neighbor_list;  // neighbors
    int num_colors;             // number of colors currently used by the node; current color will be in [0, num_colors)
    int current_color;          // color of the node
    set<int> conflict_list_H;     // colors not to be used by nodes with higher distance in the hierarchy
    set<int> conflict_list_L;     // colors not to be used by nodes with higher distance in the hierarchy
};


void Graph::dist_cr_algorithm(int root_node, double p, int iterations) {
    // some code
    msg message;
    // some code
        // process received messages
        if( !node_obj[node].message_list.empty() ) {
            //cout << "Messages received" << endl;
            for(int item = 0; item < node_obj[node].message_list.size(); item++) {
                // update distance to root node
                if( node_obj[node].message_list[item].sender_distance + 1 < node_obj[node].l_distance )
                    node_obj[node].l_distance = node_obj[node].message_list[item].sender_distance + 1;
                // update dictionary of two-hops neighbors
                for(int thn_idx = 0; thn_idx < node_obj[node].message_list[item].neighbor_list.size(); thn_idx++)
                    node_obj[node].two_hops_n.insert(node_obj[node].message_list[item].neighbor_list[thn_idx]);
                // update maximum number of colors, if necessary
                node_obj[node].c_max = max(node_obj[node].c_max, node_obj[node].message_list[item].num_colors);
            }
            // remove node from neighbors list
            node_obj[node].two_hops_n.erase(node);

            set<int> received_ids;
            set<int> tmp_conflicts;
            vector<int> received_H_colors;
            vector<int> received_all_colors;
            for(int item = node_obj[node].message_list.size()-1; item >= 0 ; item--) {
                if( received_ids.find(node_obj[node].message_list[item].sender) == received_ids.end() ) {
                    // most recent message from this sender
                    received_ids.insert(node_obj[node].message_list[item].sender);
                    // add H conflicts
                    for(set<int>::iterator IT = node_obj[node].message_list[item].conflict_list_H.begin();
                            IT != node_obj[node].message_list[item].conflict_list_H.end(); IT++)
                        tmp_conflicts.insert(*IT);

                    // add L conflicts if item has lesser distance
                    if(node_obj[node].message_list[item].sender_distance < node_obj[node].l_distance) {
                        for(set<int>::iterator IT = node_obj[node].message_list[item].conflict_list_L.begin();
                                IT != node_obj[node].message_list[item].conflict_list_L.end(); IT++)
                            tmp_conflicts.insert(*IT);
                    }
                    // also add its color
                    if( node_obj[node].message_list[item].sender_distance <=  node_obj[node].l_distance )   // check this
                        tmp_conflicts.insert(node_obj[node].message_list[item].current_color);
                    //
                    if( node_obj[node].message_list[item].sender_distance < node_obj[node].l_distance )
                        received_H_colors.push_back( node_obj[node].message_list[item].current_color );
                    received_all_colors.push_back( node_obj[node].message_list[item].current_color );
                }
            }
            // try to resolve conflicts
            if( tmp_conflicts.size() )
                // and change color if possible
                node_obj[node].l_color = resolve_conflict(tmp_conflicts, node_obj[node].l_color, node_obj[node].c_max);
            // detect H conflicts
            msg.conflict_list_H = detect_H_conflicts(received_H_colors);
            msg.conflict_list_L = detect_L_conflicts(received_all_colors, node_obj[node].l_color);

            // clear the message list
            node_obj[node].message_list.clear();
        }
        // other code

}
```

Comment: When posting code and error messages together, try to add the line information to the posted code. In the simplest way, just add a comment `// Following is line 308: expected unqualified-id before '.' token`. That will help others go straight to the line where the compiler complains much more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name `msg` that you are trying to assign to `conflict_list_H` and `conflict_list_L` members of is a type; I think you meant `message` (your object) instead.

Comment: oh, I see, I must be really tired

Comment: If you have a naming convention that distinguishes types and instances, it becomes really hard to make this kind of error.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
message.conflict_list_H = detect_H_conflicts(received_H_colors);
message.conflict_list_L = detect_L_conflicts(received_all_colors, node_obj[node].l_color);
```